# How to delete some directories after their client workspaces are deleted in perforce?

Tags: linux, perforce, p4v, vms

I am working on perforce on Linux and VMS.

I have created 3 directories, each of which has a client name and .p4rc file and mapping.

After some work, I do not need these directories.

I used perf client -d  to delete the client workspaces.

But, the directories are still there.

I want to delete them.

May I use rm command to do that manually ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you've deleted the client, then there should be no problem deleting the directory. In fact, they aren't even that strongly linked.